Book in which a hunter from Texas is transported to a magical world where he becomes the protector of two infant dragons
In this story, the protagonist, a hunter from Texas, is transported to a magical world where he discovers two dragon eggs. As the dragons hatch, he becomes their protector. The local nobles, who see dragons as symbols of power, are not happy with an outsider having such influence. One of the noble families, who are known as the Riders, send their daughter to find and confront the main character, leading to a series of conflicts and alliances.
The story can be found on Wattpad and has a blue and purple cover.

Is this Wild Rider (Dragon Castaway Book 1) (2018) by B.Urich...?

Reeling from a devastating loss Jake McCall takes refuge in the Texas hill country hoping to find peace. Tranquility however, is the last thing that fate has in store for him. Caught up in a violent storm Jake finds himself a castaway in another world where social classes are set in stone and powerful dragon lords use their riders to enforce their will.
Out of the frying pan into the fire, Jake finds himself in the center of a whole new storm as he becomes the guardian of newly born twin dragons. Holing up in the wilds he vows to protect his new charges but by riding them, he has broken an old taboo, a privilege that the high nobles of this world jealously guard and a situation that Jake cannot stand. As he clashes with his new world, a group of dragon rider cadets is sent to investigate, one of whom hides a dangerous secret of their own.


